# Pass page param to Python CDK API Gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, aws-cdk

I have an API gateway which calls a lambda function that forwards the request to an external API, so the cdk python infrastructure is:

API http method > lambda function using the requests library > external API

The API has a pre-set JQL params that can paginate the responses and define what page to start at. So for example, the external API will be expecting:

```
&startAt=0&maxResults=50
```

I wish to adapt the API gateway request to pass the chosen page number as a parameter.

For example, sending a GET request to list all items within the external API service and choose to start at page 2 of paginated responses of 5 items each:

```
page number = extract_x(event)

&startAt={chosen_page_number}&maxResults=50
```

I know I need to somehow add the mapping template to the lambda/API integration request_parameters argument in CDK but cannot find any examples of this online and the documentation only talks about this at a high level.

I am using basic lambda integration for a rest API:

```
integration = apigateway.LambdaIntegration(hello,
    proxy=False,
    request_parameters={
        "integration.request.querystring.who": "method.request.querystring.who"
    },
    allow_test_invoke=True,
    request_templates={
        "application/json": JSON.stringify({"action": "sayHello", "poll_id": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params('who'))"})
    },
    passthrough_behavior=apigateway.PassthroughBehavior.NEVER,
    integration_responses=[apigateway.IntegrationResponse(
        status_code="200",
        response_templates={
            "application/json": JSON.stringify({"state": "ok", "greeting": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.body)"})
        },
        response_parameters={
            "method.response.header._content-_type": "'application/json'",
            "method.response.header._access-_control-_allow-_origin": "'*'",
            "method.response.header._access-_control-_allow-_credentials": "'true'"
        }
    ), apigateway.IntegrationResponse(
        selection_pattern="""(
        |.)+""",
        status_code="400",
        response_templates={
            "application/json": JSON.stringify({"state": "error", "message": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.path('$.errorMessage'))"})
        },
        response_parameters={
            "method.response.header._content-_type": "'application/json'",
            "method.response.header._access-_control-_allow-_origin": "'*'",
            "method.response.header._access-_control-_allow-_credentials": "'true'"
        }
    )
    ]
)
```

Is it possible for anyone to provide a simple working example of adding a parameter to an API gateway construction in the python cdk?

Comment: You are already getting one parameter with "poll_id": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params('who'))". You can add further paremeters into the template, or not?

Comment: This is just a template from a documentation example without much of a description of what these parts do or how they integrate with other constructs. This is not application code.